# Can I chose among H1-H6 tags based on font size?

Tags: html, tags, font-size

I am an old timer coder from when there wasn't CSS and when we used HTML only to embellish pages. I am saying this then my question will make sense.

OK being tags h1 to h6 set to define importance in page contents is wrong to chose different H tag based on font size in order to match the design?

For instances can I use H4 in the main title of a page just because it has the right size while H1 is too big?

Or in such case I should use H1 and restyle it to the font size I want instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use `<h4>` in the main title of a page just because it has the right size while `<h1>` is too big?

You can, but it is not *semantically correct*. CSS should be used for styling purposes. You can read about semantics and the benefits of writing semantic markup [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics).

Answer (score 2):

You can specifically mention the tag sizes in css file. First one set h4 tag 20px, second shrink 50% of original h4 tag size's.

```
h4 {
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

or

```
h4 {
font-size: 50%;
}
```